# Is there a way to pass a value only for a second generic but not first one which has default value in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, koa, typescript-generics

**Koa Middleware type definition**

```
// @types/koa

type Middleware<StateT = DefaultState, CustomT = DefaultContext> = compose.Middleware<
    ParameterizedContext<StateT, CustomT>
>;
```

**Expect**

```
// src/middleware/cookie.ts

import { ExtendableContext, Middleware } from "koa";

type CookieContext = ExtendableContext & {
  cookie: string;
}

const parseCookieMiddleware: Middleware</*wanna skip passing generic here to use default type(DefaultState)*/, CookieContext> = async (ctx, next) => {
  //parse cookie here
  await next();
};
```

I just can pass DefaultState or create wrappedMiddlewareType,
but Koa type defenition gives us default value.
So I just wanna skip unnecessary step.

Thank you for reading.
Have a nice day!